# NetBeans 11.3 does not build properly the project?

Tags: java, build, netbeans-8, netbeans-11

I've installed on my pc NetBeans 11.3 and imported my old project from NetBeans 8.0.2. 
Initally it worked fine, but recently it starts to generate some error like Http 500 or Http 404 (this is very strage because there's nothing wrong with the paths).
If i build and clean the project with the older version everything works fine, even with the 11.3 version, but if i make some server-side changes it gives me the previous error or sometimes InvocationTargetException.
Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: Looks like you have an error somewhere and it's not compiling correctly. Hard to pinpoint the cause without knowing anything about your code.

Comment: Sounds like you need to restart your server when you have made changes to it.